# Pylint message in VSCode doesn't show the message ID

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, lint, pylint

I use `pylint` in `vscode`, the output `pylint` message does not have the message ID (e.g. `E1011`). How to configure the `pylint` in `vscode` to control the style of output message?
The output of pylint in my vscode is like this:

`Instance of 'TheanoConfigParser' has no 'floatX' member pylint(no-member) [32, 61]`

but l want to show the ID of this message.

```
vscode: 1.38.0
python: 3.7.4
pylint: 2.3.1
```